# Rails 4 - Couldn't find User without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails, so any explanation & advise would much appreciated.

- i have a webpage in which i would like any `user` to view that page not just the `current_user`, but i am unsure how to correctly define the instance variable `@user` in my controller
- in my `static_pages_controller.rb` i have the below action `recruiterpg`

static_pages_controller.rb

```
  def recruiterpg
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @adverts = @user.adverts
    @applications = @user.forms
  end
```

- in my controller, i have defined `user` as `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` but this breaks my code in the views; `views/static_pages/recruiterpg.html.erb`
- when i define `user` as `@user = current_user` my code in the views works perfectly fine

> what am trying to do is: for my views, the `recruiterpg.html.erb`, i would like
>   any `user` to be able to view the page not only the `current_user` to
>   view the page. Could one kindly advise me and explain to me how to
>   define `@user` correctly in my `status_pages_controller.rb`. i also
>   tried `@user = User.find(params[:id])` but my code still breaks in the
>   views - i get the error message

```
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

Comment: Do you have a `user_id` param?

Comment: `def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :firstname, :lastname, :companyname, :number, :hear, :image, :link, :jobtitle, :staffnumber, :company_id, :category_hear_id, :status)
    end` i don't seem to have a `user_id param`  - can i define user then as `@user = User.find(params[:id])`?

Comment: What does the link and route for `recruiterpg` look like?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "have a webpage in which i would like any user to view that page not just the current_user?" Whichever user views a given page *is* the current_user, as current_user is a completely relative value.

Comment: route: `get     'dashboard',              to: 'static_pages#recruiterpg'`

Comment: Please add additional information into the question instead of smashing it into comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're new, here is some information for you:

---

**User Story**

Firstly, the best way to resolve errors is to identify your [*user story*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story).

A "user story" is a software principle in which you put the "user's perspective" first -- explaining how the software should work in conditions defined from how the user engages with it.

One of the main issues you have with your question is your user story is very weak; it's hard to decifer what you're trying to achieve.

Next time you ask a question, you should try your hardest to describe how the user *should* see your app, before providing code snippets :)

---

**Controller**

Your main issue is an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

An antipattern is basically a "hack" which will likely break another part of your app in future. Kind of like duct tape for software):

```
#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def recruiterpg
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @adverts = @user.adverts
      @applications = @user.forms
    end
end
```

So you're showing a *static page* but yet you want to populate it with data?

Hmm...

What you *should* be doing is something like the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :recruiters, only: :index #-> url.com/users/:user_id/recruiters
end

#app/controllers/recruiters_controller.rb
class RecruitersController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
      @adverts = @user.adverts
      @applications = @user.forms
   end
end
```

This will allow you to populate the following view:

```
#app/views/recruiters/index.html.erb
<%= @adverts %>
```

--

It's important to note the *structure* of the controller / routes here.

The issue you have is that you're calling a "static page" and expecting to have params available to find a `User`. This can *only* happen if you have params available...

---

**Params**

Rails is not magic, and as such if you want to look up a user, you have to provide the parameters to do so.

This is why you're able to look up `current_user` -- the params are already set for this user.

As such, you'll need to use something called [*nested routes*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in order to attain a user ID *other* than that of `current_user`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :recruiters #-> url.com/users/:user_id/recruiters
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you are passing a user_id to the recruiterpg action.  For example, try this url in your browser (set user_id to a known id in the `users` table):

http://localhost:3000/dashboard?user_id=1

A suggested modification to your action:

```
def recruiterpg
  @user = User.find params.require(:user_id)
  @adverts = @user.adverts
  @applications = @user.forms
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If params[:user_id] isn't defined, you want to find a way to make visible what *is* being defined.

If you throw the following statements into your controller...

```
def recruiterpg
  ...
  puts params
  ...
end
```

...you should see something like the following get spit out in your console when you load the page...

```
{"controller"=>"static_pages", "action"=>"recruiterpg", "id"=>"49"}
```

Take a look at [the](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) Rails guide for parameters. They can get defined in one of three ways.

One: **As a query string** similar to Sean's answer above.

Two: **Routing parameters**. See section 4.3 in the Rails guide. In your case, that would mean you should have something like the following in `routes.rb`:

```
get '/dashboard/:user_id' => 'staticpages#recruiterpg'
```

Note that there's nothing magic about `:user_id` in that string.

Three: **From a form** which it doesn't seem like applies here, since a user isn't submitting data.